# Create SQL Server 2005 database deployment setup with custom configuration

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005

I have created a project - now I have to deploy it on the client side. I have SQL Server 2005 installed, but it's not possible to install it in client side, as it is illegal.

I want to create a database deployment setup with my custom configuration to map it with ADO.NET Entity Framework. Config such as instance name, username, pass, etc. How can I do this?